# ExpressJs Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'prototype' of undefined view.js

Tags: node.js, typescript, express

This is my first time working with React + ExpressJs + Typescript
I got the following error in the node_modules which I'm not sure where it come from. I already installed the types package for both node and expressjs.

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'prototype' of undefined
(anonymous function)
Z:/Project/sandbox-app/node_modules/express/lib/response.js:42
  39 |  * @public
  40 |  */
  41 | 
> 42 | var res = Object.create(http.ServerResponse.prototype)
  43 | 
  44 | /**
  45 |  * Module exports.
```

Here is the code where I setup the Express server

```
import express from "express"
import bodyParser from "body-parser"

const app = express()
const port = 3000

app.use(bodyParser.json())
app.use(
  bodyParser.urlencoded({
    extended: true,
  })
)

app.get("/", (request, response) => {
  response.json({ info: "Node.js, Express, and Postgres API" })
})
app.listen(port, () => {
  console.log(`App running on port ${port}.`)
})
```

Full stack trace

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'prototype' of undefined
(anonymous function)
Z:/Project/sandbox-app/node_modules/express/lib/response.js:42
  39 |  * @public
  40 |  */
  41 | 
> 42 | var res = Object.create(http.ServerResponse.prototype)
  43 | 
  44 | /**
  45 |  * Module exports.
View compiled
./node_modules/express/lib/response.js
http://localhost:3000/static/js/0.chunk.js:81472:30
__webpack_require__
Z:/Project/sandbox-app/webpack/bootstrap:851
  848 | 
  849 | __webpack_require__.$Refresh$.init();
  850 | try {
> 851 |     modules[moduleId].call(module.exports, module, module.exports, hotCreateRequire(moduleId));
      | ^  852 | } finally {
  853 |     __webpack_require__.$Refresh$.cleanup(moduleId);
  854 | }
View compiled
fn
Z:/Project/sandbox-app/webpack/bootstrap:150
  147 |         );
  148 |         hotCurrentParents = [];
  149 |     }
> 150 |     return __webpack_require__(request);
      | ^  151 | };
  152 | var ObjectFactory = function ObjectFactory(name) {
  153 |     return {
View compiled
./node_modules/express/lib/express.js
Z:/Project/sandbox-app/node_modules/express/lib/express.js:22
__webpack_require__
Z:/Project/sandbox-app/webpack/bootstrap:851
  848 | 
  849 | __webpack_require__.$Refresh$.init();
  850 | try {
> 851 |     modules[moduleId].call(module.exports, module, module.exports, hotCreateRequire(moduleId));
      | ^  852 | } finally {
  853 |     __webpack_require__.$Refresh$.cleanup(moduleId);
  854 | }
View compiled
fn
Z:/Project/sandbox-app/webpack/bootstrap:150
  147 |         );
  148 |         hotCurrentParents = [];
  149 |     }
> 150 |     return __webpack_require__(request);
      | ^  151 | };
  152 | var ObjectFactory = function ObjectFactory(name) {
  153 |     return {
View compiled
./node_modules/express/index.js
Z:/Project/sandbox-app/node_modules/express/index.js:11
__webpack_require__
Z:/Project/sandbox-app/webpack/bootstrap:851
  848 | 
  849 | __webpack_require__.$Refresh$.init();
  850 | try {
> 851 |     modules[moduleId].call(module.exports, module, module.exports, hotCreateRequire(moduleId));
      | ^  852 | } finally {
  853 |     __webpack_require__.$Refresh$.cleanup(moduleId);
  854 | }
View compiled
fn
Z:/Project/sandbox-app/webpack/bootstrap:150
  147 |         );
  148 |         hotCurrentParents = [];
  149 |     }
> 150 |     return __webpack_require__(request);
      | ^  151 | };
  152 | var ObjectFactory = function ObjectFactory(name) {
  153 |     return {
View compiled
▶ 2 stack frames were collapsed.
__webpack_require__
Z:/Project/sandbox-app/webpack/bootstrap:851
  848 | 
  849 | __webpack_require__.$Refresh$.init();
  850 | try {
> 851 |     modules[moduleId].call(module.exports, module, module.exports, hotCreateRequire(moduleId));
      | ^  852 | } finally {
  853 |     __webpack_require__.$Refresh$.cleanup(moduleId);
  854 | }
View compiled
fn
Z:/Project/sandbox-app/webpack/bootstrap:150
  147 |         );
  148 |         hotCurrentParents = [];
  149 |     }
> 150 |     return __webpack_require__(request);
      | ^  151 | };
  152 | var ObjectFactory = function ObjectFactory(name) {
  153 |     return {
View compiled
1
http://localhost:3000/static/js/main.chunk.js:1384:18
__webpack_require__
Z:/Project/sandbox-app/webpack/bootstrap:851
  848 | 
  849 | __webpack_require__.$Refresh$.init();
  850 | try {
> 851 |     modules[moduleId].call(module.exports, module, module.exports, hotCreateRequire(moduleId));
      | ^  852 | } finally {
  853 |     __webpack_require__.$Refresh$.cleanup(moduleId);
  854 | }
View compiled
checkDeferredModules
Z:/Project/sandbox-app/webpack/bootstrap:45
  42 |  }
  43 |  if(fulfilled) {
  44 |      deferredModules.splice(i--, 1);
> 45 |      result = __webpack_require__(__webpack_require__.s = deferredModule[0]);
     | ^  46 |  }
  47 | }
  48 | 
View compiled
Array.webpackJsonpCallback [as push]
Z:/Project/sandbox-app/webpack/bootstrap:32
  29 |  deferredModules.push.apply(deferredModules, executeModules || []);
  30 | 
  31 |  // run deferred modules when all chunks ready
> 32 |  return checkDeferredModules();
     | ^  33 | };
  34 | function checkDeferredModules() {
  35 |  var result;
View compiled
(anonymous function)
http://localhost:3000/static/js/main.chunk.js:1:75
```

Comment: I think your import syntax is wrong. It should be `import * as express from 'express'`.

Comment: I dont think so, because it is ES6 import syntax

Comment: Yeah I looked up the proper way to export express. My apologies for the earlier, misleading comment. Can you provide the full error stack trace?

Comment: I just added full stack trace to the post, thanks for giving a look